# Porting to WinJS without modifying libraries

Tags: winjs

Is there a way to port existing HTML5 apps to WinJS without modifying libraries?  Going through each library and wrapping innerHTML calls with execUnsafeLocalFunction is such a dirty hack.

Could I load the base page as unsafe some how?  Loading everything in an iframe is just displaying an empty white box.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make things work with an iframe if you put it in the [right context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781215.aspx) with ms-appx-web:

```
<iframe src="ms-appx-web:///path/to/iframe.html"></iframe>
```

The downside is you won't be able to get at WinRT APIs from there. Unfortunately there isn't a way to selectively disable parts of SafeHTML. While you could globally disable it by doing some hacks to replace HTMLElement.innerHTML so that it calls execUnsafeLocalFunction implicitly, that would also open you up to script injection attacks which could cause your app to be rejected from the store.

Another option is to actually navigate the root page into the web context:

```
window.location.href = "ms-appx-web:///path/to/iframe.html";
```

I believe you then may be able to have an invisible iframe back to the local context (ms-appx) and use the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to communicate across the boundary as needed.